# How to handle bookmark and absolute positioned div

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a anchor bookmark that when clicked goes behind my main header absolutely positioned div. I need a solution to this that doesn't require future html programmers to alter the way they use anchor bookmarks. Any suggestions on how to fix this?

Please see my example that illustrates the issue.

http://jsfiddle.net/8dErs/

```
  <a name="5"></a><h1>Article 5</h1>
```

Comment: try this http://jsfiddle.net/mohammadAdil/8dErs/13/

Comment: +Mohammad, thks, but I need the header to stay where it is. Your solution makes the header disappear from view.

Comment: @MohammadAdil just thought I'd follow up on this. I'm not getting any answers on this. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

That is because the top navigation is positionally fixed, and therefore taken out of document flow and no longer considered as part of the flow.

If you want the anchor to scroll such that the header is displayed underneath the header (therefore not visually obstructed), you will have to rely on JS to recalculate the scroll position of the page.

p/s: I never recommend positionally fixing elements that are too big. There is also an error in your JS - the last line should be `});` not `}`.

Comment: terry, what would be an example of using JS to recalculate scroll position on page?

Comment: just thought I'd follow up on this. I'm not getting any answers on this. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You might try something where the scroll 'top' isn't the actual screen/window top but rather the location of a positioned div, the parent of the content. So you calculate the scroll based on about 180px which is about 5px below your nav.

But, on a long page, if you start manually scrolling, the header will stay there anyway so maybe using jquery with animation along the Y and all within it's own div would be simpler. That way, you can avoid using fixed.

Comment: Thanks Kelly for the answer but my expertise is way below this. Are you able to adjust my jsfiddle to show me what you mean?

Comment: just thought I'd follow up on this. I'm not getting any answers on this. Thanks!